# How do Laravel and Docker play together?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, virtualization

I want to get into Laravel development. As per Laravel's installation guide, I have installed Docker first, which was a first for me.
But for me to finally install Laravel, I need to have a docker container running.

How so, when I don't yet know what tools I am going to use? I haven't even been able to install Laravel! So what do I have to do? Is there a public Dockerfile / image or something like that that I can run so I can install Laravel and start getting into that?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You can always try [Laradock](http://laradock.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this official install script https://laravel.build/example-app

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos

Comment: I cannot install that without having a container running.

Comment: What OS did you run your application? I run that install script successfully on my Mac without a running container, only it needs is a running docker.

Comment: Windows. It wants a running container, sadly.

Comment: As the official document says,`Before we create a new Laravel application on your Windows machine, make sure to install Docker Desktop. Next, you should ensure that Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) is installed and enabled. WSL allows you to run Linux binary executables natively on Windows 10. Information on how to install and enable WSL2 can be found within Microsoft's developer environment documentation.` What do you mean it wants a running container?

Comment: It's the error I received. I had the Docker program opened but it wouldn't let me use the build script. I am installing Laradock as we speak and I hope this works